# Android collapse search button

Tags: android

I can't collapse my search button in actionbar.This is my menu xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
      <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="Ara"
          android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" 
          app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>

</menu>
```

I am working with this classes in main activity

```
import io.socket.IOAcknowledge;
import io.socket.IOCallback;
import io.socket.SocketIO;
import io.socket.SocketIOException;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.impact.ribony.adapter.TabsPagerAdapter;
import com.koushikdutta.async.future.Future;
import com.koushikdutta.async.future.FutureCallback;
import com.koushikdutta.ion.Ion;
```

Menu create method:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

I am using min sdk version 14.I am pressing to search button and nothing happens.Why button is not collapsing ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement `SearchView.OnQueryTextListener`, then

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    InputMethodManager imm =
            (InputMethodManager)mActivity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchView.getWindowToken(), 0);
    return true;
}
```

BTW, SearchView initialization should be performed in `onCreateOptionsMenu`:

```
MenuItem searchItem;
SearchView searchView;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    searchView = (SearchView)searchItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setQueryHint(getResources().getString(R.string.{hint})); //if you want a custom hint
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    EditText et = (EditText)searchView.findViewById(searchView.getContext().getResources()
            .getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null));
    et.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.{color})); // if you want to change hint color
    et.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter({max_length}) }); // if you want to set max. text limit
    return true
}
```

Comment: Do you know this error ? The method onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu, MenuInflater) of type MainActivity must override or implement a supertype method

Comment: Ah, sorry, I included onCreateOptionsMenu() from Fragment implementation. Edited for Activity implementation.

Comment: Thanks it's fixed but I have one more problem.The type MainActivity must implement the inherited abstract method SearchView.OnQueryTextListener.onQueryTextChange(String) I am getting this error

Comment: You should implement the interface in your Activity as follows: `public class MainActivity extends {whatever is extended} implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener`. If you're using support library, use `SearchViewCompat` instead of `SearchView`

Comment: I can't extend from Activity.I am using like this public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements 
ActionBar.TabListener,ConversationFragment.OnGetFromUserClickListener,SearchView.OnQueryTextListener

Comment: As above, If you're using support library, use `SearchViewCompat` instead of `SearchView`. Please refer to the documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SearchViewCompat.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59928/discussion-between-alexander-zhak-and-tolgay-toklar).